# Combining Policy Classes - Template Template Parameters & Variadic Templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-inheritance

I am wondering if it's possible to combine policy classes using variadic template-template parameters such that each policy may have it's own template pack.  It seems like you can only share a single template pack amongst all policies but I hope that's not the case.

The following seems to be what's possible:

```
template <
    class T,
    template <class, typename...>   class Policy1,
    template <class, typename...>   class Policy2,
    template <class, typename...>   class Policy3,
    typename... Args    
>
struct PolicyClass 
    : public Policy1     <ObjT, Args...>
    , public Policy2     <ObjT, Args...>
    , public Policy3     <ObjT, Args...>    {}
```

I'm hoping each policy can have it's own pack so I could make something like this (?):

```
template <class T>
struct implementedPolicy1 {};
template <class T>
struct implementedPolicy2 {};
template <class T, class A>
struct implementedPolicy3 {};

PolicyClass <ObjT, 
             implementedPolicy1,
             implementedPolicy2,
             implementedPolicy3<AType>
            >
```

The idea being each of the policies are all using the same object type but the third has some further templating.  I know that's incorrect code above - just trying to illustrate what I'd like to be able to do.

Thanks

Comment: What's `ObjT` ? The current class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to delimit between the packs.

```
// helper template.  Using `std::tuple<>` instead is another option.
template<class...>struct type_list {};

// base, note no body:
template <
    class T,
    template <class, typename...>   class Policy0,
    template <class, typename...>   class Policy1,
    template <class, typename...>   class Policy2,
    typename... Packs
>
struct PolicyClass;

// specialization:
template <
    class T,
    template <class, typename...>   class Policy0,
    template <class, typename...>   class Policy1,
    template <class, typename...>   class Policy2,
    typename... A0s,
    typename... A1s,
    typename... A2s
>
struct PolicyClass<
  T, Policy1, Policy2, Policy3,
  type_list<A0s...>, type_list<A1s...>, type_list<A2s...>
>
: Policy0<T, A0s...>, Policy1<T, A1s...>, Policy2<T, A2s...> {}
```

where I pack each policies extra arguments into a `type_list`.

In theory you could do fancier things, like have particular "tag" types being the delimiters, but it ends up being a lot of gymnastics.

```
PolicyClass< int, bob, eve, alice, type_list<>, type_list<double>, type_list<char, char, char> > foo;
```

will create

```
PolicyClass: bob<int>, alice<int, double>, eve<int, char, char, char>
```

roughly.

Comment: Thanks @Yakk - How would I go about using this then?

Answer (score 3):

I have never been fan of template template parameters, and this is one other instance I would avoid them:

```
template <typename T, typename... Policies>
struct PolicyClass: Policies... {};
```

will just work with arbitrary policies:

```
using PC = PolicyClass<int,
                       LifetimePolicy<LP::Extended>,
                       DurabilityPolicy<3600, DP::Seconds>
                       StoragePolicy<int, SP::InMemory>>;
```

Comment: Thanks @Matthieu  That would be useful in some cases.  For this particular instance I want specifically 3 policies at all times since functions of the policies are used in a PolicyClass member function.

Comment: You can actually use an unbounded number of policies with variadic templates; as long as they have a uniform interface. If you wish to restrict it to 3 though, `template <typename T, typename P1, typename P2, typename P3> struct PC: P1, P2, P3 {};` works very well too.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you may have something like:

```
template <class T,
          template <class> class Policy1,
          template <class> class Policy2,
          template <class> class Policy3>
struct PolicyClass : public Policy1<ObjT>,
                     public Policy2<ObjT>,
                     public Policy3<ObjT>
{};

template <class T> struct implementedPolicy1 {};
template <class T> struct implementedPolicy2 {};
template <class T, class A> struct implementedPolicy3 {};

// Adapt the policy interface
template <class T>
using myImplementedPolicy3 = implementedPolicy3<T, AType>; // Assuming AType exist

PolicyClass <ObjT, implementedPolicy1, implementedPolicy2, myImplementedPolicy3> policies;
```